# Role based menu items using angular 4 with url query string

Tags: angular, authentication, routes

I want to show the menu items based on the user roles like i have Admin, User, Manager etc. So my question is how can i show the menu items based on user roles. I have been given the url as http://www.example.com/searchsupplier?type=admin. Based on the query string type=admin i need to show the menu items using angular. Means if the query string has type=admin then i need to show Dashboard - Users - Others and if type=user then i need to show My Profile etc. So how can i achieve this. Can anyone give me small example with query string .

The code i have tried in the component

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.route.queryParams
        .filter(params => params.type)
        .subscribe(params => {
            console.log(params); //{type: "admin"}
            this.type = params.type;
            console.log(this.type);

            if(this.type == "admin"){
                console.log("ADMIN PAGE");                
                    //this.router.navigate(['dashboard'], { queryParams: { type: this.type } });
                    this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
            }else if(this.type == "national"){
                console.log("NATIONAL PAGE");
            }else if(this.type == "warrington"){
                console.log("WARRINGTON PAGE");
            }else if(this.type == "subcontractorAdmin"){
                console.log("SUB CONTRACOTR ADMIN PAGE");
            }else if(this.type == "subcontractorManager"){
                console.log("SUB CONTRACTOR MANAGER PAGE");
            }else{
                console.log("OTHERS PAGE");
            }
        });
```

But i am not getting any clue that how to show the menu items based on the users from the url query string. The navigation is working fine but how to hide and show the menu items based on the roles.

If the url query string has the params as type=admin then i have to show all the menu items.

But in header.component.html, how can i apply from the url query string type=admin or type=national etc.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="'type' == 'admin'">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="navigateExternal('http://localhostL:4200/dashboard','_self')">Dashboard</a>
              </li>
              <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="'type' == 'admin'">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="navigateExternal('http:localhostL:4200/supplier-list','_self')">Suppliers</a>
              </li>
              <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="'type' == 'admin'">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="navigateExternal('http:localhostL:4200/compliance-supplier-list','_self')">Compliance</a>
              </li>
              <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="'type' == 'admin'">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="navigateExternal('http:localhostL:4200/admin-invoice-list','_self')">Invoicing</a>
              </li>
              <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="'type' == 'admin'">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="navigateExternal('http:localhostL:4200/internal-user-list','_self')">User Management</a>

              </li>
              <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="'type' == 'admin'">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="navigateExternal('http:localhostL:4200/node/add/upload_weight_csv','_self')">Weight Ticket</a>

              </li>
              <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="'type' == 'admin'">
                <a routerLink="/searchsupplier">Search</a>
              </li>
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try writing anything so far? This sounds like an homework so before asking at least put some effort in it and try to do something by yourself and then come here if you have any issues.

Comment: @FilipRistic: I have added the code which i have tried. Please help me out.

Comment: In the above code i have added the conditional *ngIf directive but when i navigate the url with type=admin then all the menu items are getting hidden. Can anyone help me in this?